# A better query to find list of Employess who have max salary in their department?

Tags: sql, sql-server, logic

I have a table: `[tblEmp]`

```
EmpId | EmpName | DeptId
```

and a table `[tblSalary]`

```
EmpId | Salary
```

and I need to find the list of employees who have max salary in their department.

I could achieve this by:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblEmp
JOIN tblSal ON tblSal.EmpId = tblEmp.EmpId
WHERE LTRIM(STR(deptid)) + LTRIM(STR(salary)) IN (
    SELECT LTRIM(STR(deptid)) + LTRIM(STR(MAX(salary)))
    FROM tblSal
    JOIN tblEmp ON tblSal.EmpId = tblEmp.EmpId
    GROUP BY DeptId
)
```

Is there a better way to achieve the list ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

> Returns the sequential number of a row within a partition of a result
>   set, starting at 1 for the first row in each partition.

Something like

```
;WITH Employees AS (
        SELECT  e.*,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY e.DeptId ORDER BY s.salary DESC) RowID
        FROM    [tblEmp] e INNER JOIN
                [tblSalary] s ON    e.EmpId = s.EmpId
)
SELECT  *
FROM    Employees
WHERE   RowID = 1
```

This will however not return Employees that have the same salry in the same department.

For that you might want to look at [RANK (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) or [DENSE_RANK (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx)instead of ROW_NUMBER.

> **Rank** : Returns the rank of each row within the partition of a result set. The
>   rank of a row is one plus the number of ranks that come before the row
>   in question.
>
> If two or more rows tie for a rank, each tied rows receives the same
>   rank.
>
> **Dense_Rank** : Returns the rank of rows within the partition of a result
>   set, without any gaps in the ranking. The rank of a row is one plus
>   the number of distinct ranks that come before the row in question.

Comment: Thanks for providing a better approach and proper explanation for RANK and Dense_Rank function.

Answer (score 2):

This is typically something where you use the analytical functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT tblSal.*, tblEmp.*,
              RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY tblEmp.deptid ORDER BY tblSal.salary DESC) as SalaryRank
       FROM tblEmp
       JOIN tblSal ON tblSal.EmpId = tblEmp.EmpId
      )
WHERE SalaryRank = 1
```